# Xcode 4.6 doesn't recognize linked frameworks correctly for Xcode 5.0 created project

Tags: ios, frameworks, import, xcode4.6, xcode5

I've created a project in Xcode 5.0 (yes, Developer Preview) for the beta iOS7 software because I wanted to play around with the new beta stuff. But I actually decided to submit the App I was playing around with to the App Store and since this is not possible with preview Xcode versions I fixed all compatibility issues to make the code work with Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS 6. Except for one thing.

And that's **importing third party frameworks** like Flurry (analytics framework) or Crashlytics (crash reporting framework).

Both are correctly imported and set up with targets (it's all working in Xcode 5.0) but I'm getting a `'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found` in the line I'm importing the needed classes (`#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>`) in Xcode 4.6.

The same is true for the Flurry framework analogously. The crazy thing is, both libraries show up in the targets 'Link Binary With Libraries' list, even in Xcode 4.6.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get things work in Xcode 4.6? Are there any further ways to influence the importing?

Answer (score 1):

The link binary with libraries is not the issue here.  You have to confirm your Header Search Paths in your build settings.  I think Xcode 5 might use a different variable for it, and that is why Xcode 4.6 will get confused (just a guess though).  Anyway, confirm that the path to those headers is in your Header Search Path.  The Crashlytics app will automatically add it for you, actually.